# sync_close in ruby's openssl library

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I was wondering what the attribute `sync_close` in [OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLSocket.html) is for. It says it's not documented in rdoc. I can see it in a lot of code snippets, but I can't see it's usage. What is it for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you open a socket, ie tcp, then you create the SSL layer. sync_close makes it so that both the original socket and the encrypted layer are closed together.